# ansible find (-or linux) for directories with set depth

Tags: ansible, find, depth

I'm trying to use the Ansible `find` builtin to create something similar to

```sh
find /home/user/data -maxdepth 2 -type d -name 'mul' -or -name 'sqr'
```

where `/home/user/data` has folders `a`,`b`,`c`... and in each of them could be none/one/both of `mul`- or `sqr`-directories.

It works well with that Linux query and with Ansible I tried

```yaml
   - name: find fields
      find:
        depth: 2
        paths: "/home/user/data"
        file_type: directory
        patterns:
          - 'mul'
          - 'sqr'
      register: fields
  - name: debug1
      debug:
        msg: " myitem: {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ fields.files | map(attribute='path') }}"
```

but my debug output is empty.
I could remove the `patterns` and set `depth: 1`, resulting in a list `a`,`b`,`c` and then iterate over those to find `mul` and `sqr` but that takes unnecessarily long if the lists get long.

Comment: Set ``recurse: yes``. It' is ``no`` by [default](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#parameter-recurse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vladimir said, setting `recurse: yes` solves the issue.
I'm still wondering, why, when setting `depth: 2`, `recurse: yes` is not implied.
Here is the full example:

```yaml
   - name: find fields
      find:
        depth: 2
        paths: "/home/user/data"
        file_type: directory
        recurse: yes
        patterns:
          - 'mul'
          - 'sqr'
      register: fields
  - name: debug1
      debug:
        msg: " myitem: {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ fields.files | map(attribute='path') }}"
```